# Meaning of ftp -i -v $TARGET_HOST < $SCRIPT_FILE > $LOG_FILE

Tags: unix, ftp, ksh

Can anyone tell me what is the meaning of the ftp command:
ftp -i -v $TARGET_HOST < $SCRIPT_FILE > $LOG_FILE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script connects to the FTP server on `$TARGET_HOST`, and use the content of `$SCRIPT_FILE` as a set of commands to be sent to the FTP server. The file `$LOG_FILE` then contains the logs of the FTP client.

The `-i` option removes the interactive prompt, so it is not in `$LOG_FILE`.

The `-v` option forces ftp to show all responses from the remote server, as well as report on data transfer statistics.